# Adding a user to a list with mandrill

Tags: node.js, mailchimp, mandrill

I'm trying to create a simple page on heroku to gather emails for an upcoming product launch. I'm trying to use the nodejs mandrill api wrapper to do accomplish this but it looks like there's no method for adding a user to a list. List subscription seems like it would be a really basic ESP function, am I missing something or is there some reason why this isn't included in the api.

Answer (score 1):

Mandrill doesn't store your subscribers (unlike mailchimp), only your recipients blacklisted. You have to build your own storage layer.